# Xquery get node with specific child element

Tags: xpath, xquery

I am using xquery 1.0 and have the following problem.

**My input message:**

```
<Body>
<album>
    <contents>
        <content>correct</content>
        <content>hardcore</content>
    </contents>
</album>
<album>
    <contents>
        <content>incorrect</content>
        <content>punk</content>
    </contents>
</album>
<album>
    <contents>
        <content>incorrect</content>
        <content>rock</content>
    </contents>
</album>
</Body>
```

**Desired result:**

I would like to search for the 'Album' node that contains the child element **`<content>correct</content>`** and when the node has been found I would like to pick/use the element **`<content>hardcore</content>`**. Note that the order of the album nodes is subject to change. So a first() or [1] will not be sufficient.

**What I tried:**

`if (body/album/contents/content[text()='correct']) then ???`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you probably don't need xquery for that.

```
//contents/content[.="correct"]/following-sibling::content
```

should be enough.